# GEE - S1 imagery appears as RGB instead of grayscale

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I would like to visualize a collection of VV Sentinel 1 imagery in Google Earth Engine. This is what I have done so far:

```
<// Filter the collection - VV only depending on geometry and date
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2019-10-10','2019-10-14')
    .select(['VV']);
print(s1);

//visualisation parameters  

 var viz = {
  band: 'VV',
  min: -50.0,
  max: -10,
};

// display each image in collection
function addImage(s1) { 
  var id = s1.id;
  var scene = ee.Image(s1.id);
  Map.addLayer(scene, viz, id);
  Map.centerObject(geometry,9);
}

// use map on client-side
s1.evaluate(function(s1) {  
  s1.features.map(addImage);
});>
```

Why do the results visualize as RGB? And how to avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the visualization parameters. If you see the documentation for `ee.data.getMapId` you can see in the accepted parameters: `bands` (not `band`), and it must be a list of bands. So

```
var viz = {
  bands: ['VV'],
  min: -50.0,
  max: -10,
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much!